# If I scribe a scroll of a spell I know, and then give it to another caster, is it cast as a caster of my level or of the level of the one casting it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, warlock

I am a 6th level Warlock, meaning all of my known spells are cast as if 3rd level. If I then write a scroll of one of my known 1st-level spells and hand it to an allied spellcaster, when they use it, will it be cast at 3rd level, or 1st?

Comment: Ask your GM what rules he is using for crafting/scribing a spell scroll. You may want to include it in your question as there are two somewhat different answers based on which official (albeit both optional) rules you are using (and if you are using different rules entirely, that may change the answer entirely)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### General Rules for Spell Scrolls

The level of spell scrolls are determined by the level of the spell that it contains.

Page 128 of the *Dungeon Master's Guide* provides additional information on resources required for crafting a Magic Item (which applies here)

> **Crafting a Magic Item**
>
> ...
>
> If a spell will be produced by the item being created, the creator must expend one spell slot of the spell's level for each day of the creation process. The spell's material components must also be at hand throughout the process. If the spell normally consumes those components they are consumed by the creation process. If the item will be able to produce the spell only once, as with a spell scroll, the components are consumed only once by the process. Otherwise the components are consumed once each day of the item's creation.
>
> ...

The level of a specific spell casting instance is determined by the spell slot used to cast it.

The *Player's Handbook* contains the rules for this on Page 201

> **Casting a Spell at a Higher Level**
> When a spellcaster casts a spell using a slot that is of a higher level than the spell, the spell assumes the higher level for that casting.
> ...
> Effectively, the spell expands to fill the slot it is put into.

The (optional) downtime rules for scribing a spell scroll in 5E are available in *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* on page 133.

The spell save DC and attack bonus are determined by the level of the spell. The DMG page 200 specifies what these are for spell scrolls.

Combining all of this information the resources it specifies required to scribe a scroll are:

1. The spell slot of the level you want the spell scroll to be
2. Material components for the spell
3. The spell must be among the characters known spells (for Bards, Eldritch Knights, Rangers, Arcane Trickster Rogues, Sorcerers, and Warlocks) or prepared spells (for Clerics, Druids, Paladins, and Wizards)

- Cantrips count as "Known" spells for all classes

4. Time (detemined by spell level)
5. Gold (also determined by spell level)

### Applying it to your specific situation

You as a warlock will be using one of your 3rd-level spell slots, as a result the level of the scroll is 3rd-level.

Using all of the above information the various costs required are:

1. 3rd-level spell slot
2. Material Components for the spell
3. that you know the spell
4. 1 workweek
5. 500gp

The resulting item is a spell scroll containing a 3rd-level version of your first level spell.

For example, *Charm Person* cast at 3rd-level enables the caster to target 3 creatures.

The scroll you would produce with this spell and your resources as a warlock is a 3rd-level *Charm Person* scroll (which can target up to 3 creatures) with a Save DC of 15.

The DMG on page 141 states:

> The spell is cast at the lowest possible spell level, doesn't expend any of the user's spell slots, and requires no components, unless the item's description says otherwise.

This doesn't disallow the concept of a higher level spell scroll. The specific item of a 3rd level Charm Person Spell Scroll does not exist yet, but these rules don't disallow us making it.

### Can spells have different levels to their base level, without using a spell slot?

**Yes.** Many magic items explicitly set this out:

> NECKLACE OF PRAYER BEADS
>
> ...
>
> [...] Cure wounds (2nd level) [...]

Since *Cure Wounds* exists as a 2nd-level spell (without any mention of spell slots), then a character can create a 2nd-level *Cure Wounds* *Spell Scroll*. To do so they will need to expend a 2nd-level spell slot during the crafting of said scroll per the rules from the various sections above.

This can be generalised to all spells that have the "At Higher Level" descriptor in their spell description.

Comment: You can't conflate crafting a magic item and scribing a scroll. They are two different variants for the same outcome

Comment: Scribing a spell scroll is a specific type of crafting of a magic item. They are called out explicitly in the "Crafting Magic Items" section in XGtE (page 128) as having exceptions to the general crafting rules described in the rules it lays ou.

Comment: That's a variant rule that changes how it works, you would no longer need to expend spell slots at all if you use the variant rule. They are two entirely different processes

Comment: The variant rules don't change the general crafting requirement from the DMG for using a spell slot

Comment: Yes they do, without a doubt. The requirements in XGtE are clearly listed. For example you also require Arcana proficiency which was not required in the DMG

Comment: I meant they don't completely replace it...they augment them

Answer (score 1):

### The level of a spell cast from a Spell Scroll is the lowest level for that spell.

The levels of the creator and the caster are irrelevant to the level of the spell that is cast from the scroll.

Spell Scrolls are described at *DMG p 200*.  However, they don't mention anything about how to determine the level of the spell.

Therefore, you need to refer to the Magic Item rules about casting spells from items at *DMG p141*.

> ***The spell is cast at the lowest possible spell level***, doesn't expend any of the user's spell slots, and requires no components, unless the item's description says otherwise.

This is unambiguous since the item description does not address it.  The optional rules for Scribing a Spell Scroll *(XGtE p133)* do not allow/account for spells being stored at any level other than their lowest/default spell level.

Answer (score 0):

The rules are not well written for Warlocks who create scrolls or who use rings of spell storing. They yield two equally unlikely and mutually exclusive results.

IF the spell is at it's lowest possible level using spell slots to create it, then the portion of the rule about it being the lowest possible level of the spell would limit a L6 warlock to creating with 1st level slots and he has none. No such scroll can be made.

IF the spell is at the level of the spell slots used to create it, then the portion of the rule about it being the lowest possible level of the spell would limit a L6 warlock to creating 1st level spells with 3rd level slots which isn't allowed. No such scroll can be made.

Neither of these results makes any sense from the viewpoint of the game. Becoming higher level does not make you unable to do what you could do at lower level for any other class. Becoming higher level does not make you unable to cast lower level spells that don't scale, they just don't do anything different than they did initially.

The most logical (game logic, not classical logic) is one of the following, chosen by your DM (the final arbitrator in messy rules):

- A) Warlocks may use up their available pact magic slots to scribe or cast lower level spells at the higher level ***OR*** at any lower level they would have been previously able to cast the same spell.
- B) Warlocks may ***ONLY*** use their available pact magic slots to scribe or cast lower level spells as higher level versions of the spell, regardless of whether the spell's effects scale.

Option A allows Warlocks to create standard scrolls where the spell's level is always the lowest level available, while option B allows Warlocks to use their higher level slots to create a scroll that must be the level they would use when casting the spell personally, i.e. the higher level spell that they're required to cast.

Note: Since option B creates scrolls which do not meet the requirement for being the lowest level casting of the spell, it introduces a new complexity to the scroll creation process and is likely to be less RAI than option A, although still within the possibility of RAI (considering how poorly the RAW rules address this very specific Warlock issue)